# Effect of load changes on buck converter

Tags: buck, converter, load

I know to some extent that the control block monitors the output and adjusts the duty cycle accordingly and the output changes with change in loading (that's why the control block is used in the first place)...Can anybody explain the effect of load changes on the output if a control block wasn't used at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the continuous inductor current case, a buck will follow the equation Vout = (duty cycle)*Vin.  If there's no feedback the equation still holds, but the output impedance of the converter is much higher.

You have the DCR of the inductor and FETs, trace impedance, source impedance, etc, adding up to an effective output impedance that will cause the output to droop with load current.

Comment: Hi John ,is there any formula to calculate , how output voltage changes on varying load impendences keeping duty cycle constant